# is there way to compare latest in alphabet in python

Tags: python

I want to find longest word in string. if there are same length words, i will choose the word that comes latest in the alphabet.

```
def getKey(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return len(word)

def findLongestWord(text):
    return max(text.split(), key = getKey)
```

I want to only modify getKey.
Is there some way to compare latest in alphabet

Comment: `return len(word), word`…

Comment: i think he means, the later that comes second in order ,, A , B, C...etc

Comment: can you give an example? the question is not clear.

Comment: if text = " abc bcde cdef", then findLongestWord return 'bcde'
I think i can use tuple for the max function. but to compare string return word not latest in alphabet

Answer (score 2):

i think you can do it without getkey function as

```
def find_longest(words):
    return max(sorted(words.lower().split(), reverse=True), key=len)
```

Example :

```
w = 'hello my name is something aomething , i am so happy'

print(find_longest(w))
#something
```

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the comments by @deceze, the solution is to return `len(word), word`.

The first thing that you need to for this to make sense is that when ordering tuples, the order is determined by the first value, and if the first values are equal then the second value, then the third and so on.

The second thing you need to know for this to make sense is that when ordering strings, they are ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['a','bb','ab']
response = ''
for elem in a:
    if len(elem) > len(response):
        response = elem
    elif len(elem) == len(response) and elem < response:
        response = elem
response
```

> 'ab'

Comment: i think he needs latest : bb